# Mole in image recognition

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I'm intrested in analyzing moles in images. I want to be able to find information about feats of the moles like max radius, min radius, how close the shape of the mole to ellipse, detect the edges of the mole and so on. What library would you suggest would help me achive those goals? I can program in C C++ and C# so I need a library that works with one of those languges.. Any seggustions?

Thenx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org) has all the necessary functions for the problems you mentioned. It can also do much more, so it is a good idea to build experience with it.

Comment: I did a tutorial in Open CV (EMGU CV) a while ago.. I'll check what it can give me for this project.. Thenx for your help.. more suggustions will be gladly excrpted :)
Thenx again.

Comment: OpenCV might be a bit of an over-kill for those simple functions, but it is always a nice thing to know how to use, and it will save you a lot of time.